# Setting the FillColor of MS Excel Cell using NumberFormat

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I need to set the Fill Color (Background) of the Excel Cell to Red or Green based on some threshold value.
I have used `Style.Fill.BackgroundColor` and `Style.Font.FontColor` property conditionally to fill the background color and font color but then found out that the `NumberFormat` can also be used to set the font color conditionally like this:

```
Style.NumberFormat.Format = "[Red][<=100];[Blue][>100]";
```

Is there any way I can set the fill color by using the `NumberFormat` property of the cells so that I can leave checking the condition on MS Excel itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can set the fill color by using the NumberFormat property of the cells so that I can leave checking the condition on MS Excel itself?

No. There isn't. Conditional formatting applied via `.NumberFormat` property only affects text/numbers inside a cell and not the background colour.

What you are doing is explained [here](http://searchengineland.com/easy-to-advanced-uses-of-cell-formatting-in-excel-130203).

Excel has a feature called [**Conditional Formatting**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67) which can colour both text and background depending on a condition you set. [Here's the link](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Conditional%20Formatting) (*Thanks to Manuel*)